# Where can I get the Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 LTS for Raspberry Pi?

Tags: server, raspberrypi, disk-image

Nice to meet you. I installed Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 LTS on my Raspberry Pi last December. (I used Raspberry Pi Imager)

It was necessary to reinstall, and when I started Raspberry Pi Imager, the OS that could be installed was 20.04.2.  20.04.1 was not found.

I searched for the following URL, but I couldn't find 20.04.01.
https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi

Since it is for operation check, the same Ver. As before is required.

I'm sorry, but I would appreciate your cooperation.

Comment: 20.04.2 is the next update - there is no reason to install 20.04.1 when 20.04.2 is out. Why do you think you need specifically 20.04.1?

Comment: Thanks for Artur Meinild.

Why do you think you need specifically 20.04.1?
⇒ That is because I made a mistake in the past. I was told to make a backup, but I forgot.

I repaired the software of the old product and confirmed that it works with 20.04.02, but I would like to confirm that there is no problem with the past Ver.

Comment: Fair - see answer below.

Comment: Does this help? [install Ubuntu Server on Pi](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#1-overview)

Comment: Thanks for 24601.I check it for a reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find old releases here:

http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/focal/

You would need the file `ubuntu-20.04.1-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi.img.xz` and flash this to SD card.

Comment: That was a really big help! thanks you. thank you very much Artur Meinild.